# Converting Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0 - Error, Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type'

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to convert one of my projects from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0 but some reason I get the following error...

> > Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type'(with: NSMutableURLRequest, completionHandler:(Data?, UIRLResponse?, NSError) -> Void)'
> >
> > Overloads for ‘dataTask’ exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (with: URLRequest, completionHandler:@escaping(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void), (with: URL, completionHandler: @escaping(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)

The error shows in this line from the code below...

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (responseData:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

Any suggestion?

Here is the whole code for function where the error occurs.

```
func verifyReceipt(_ transaction:SKPaymentTransaction?){
        let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!
        if let receipt = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptURL){
            //Receipt exists
            let requestContents = ["receipt-data" : receipt.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))]

            //Perform request
            do {
                let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestContents, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))

                //Build URL Request
                let storeURL = URL(string: "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")// production URL
                //let storeURL = NSURL(string: "https:/sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt") // Testing URL
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: storeURL!)
                request.httpMethod = "Post"
                request.httpBody = requestData

                let session = URLSession.shared
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (responseData:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    //

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary

                        print(json)

                        if (json.object(forKey: "status") as! NSNumber) == 0 {
                            //

                            if let latest_receipt = json["latest_receipt_info"]{
                                self.validatePurchaseArray(latest_receipt as! NSArray)
                            } else {
                                let receipt_dict = json["receipt"] as! NSDictionary
                                if let purchases = receipt_dict["in_app"] as? NSArray{
                                    self.validatePurchaseArray(purchases)
                                }
                            }

                            if transaction != nil {
                                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction!)
                            }

                            DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: { () -> Void in
                                self.delegate?.managerDidRestorePurchases()
                            })


                        } else {
                            //Debug the receipt
                            print(json.object(forKey: "status") as! NSNumber)
                        }

                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })

                task.resume()

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        } else {
            //Receipt does not exist
            print("No Receipt")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It uses a `URLRequest`, not a `NSMutableURLRequest`/`NSURLRequest`.

Comment: You right, that was the main issue. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler wants `URLRequest` and `Error`

```
 ...
 var request = URLRequest(url: storeURL!)
 request.httpMethod = "Post"
 ...
 let task = session.dataTask(with: request, 
                completionHandler: { (responseData:Data?, 
                                          response:URLResponse?, 
                                             error:Error?) -> Void in
```

I recommend to omit all type annotations

```
 let task = session.dataTask(with: request, 
                completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) -> Void in
```

Comment: `URLRequest` solved the main error but after changing that,  XCode suggested to add **as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?** to the main clousure, and it's now working. Thanks `let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{( // code } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)`

Comment: Do not cast `( // code } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)`, please read my answer carefully.

Comment: @ vadian - Hmm, I for some reason I got an error when I tried your suggestion, but now I tried it again and it worked `let task = session.dataTask(with: request,
                                            completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) -> Void in` Thanks a lot. Quick question, what would be the issue by going with the approach suggested by XCode (casting)?

Comment: The migrator from Swift 2 to Swift 3 does a terrific job, but it's not perfect. Trust is good, control is better, look up the signature of the appropriate method in the documentation.

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member 'data Task(with:completionHandler:)'

I am facing this after doing the same 

 let task = session.dataTask(with: request, 
                completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) -> Void in

Comment: @TBI Don't use `NS(Mutable)URLRequest`, `NSURL`, `NSURLResponse` `NSData`, `NSError`. Use the native Swift structs `URLRequest`, `URL`, `URLResponse`, `Data` and the protocol `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: storeURL!)
 request.httpMethod = "Post"

 let task = session.dataTask(with: request, 
                completionHandler: { (responseData:Data?, 
                                          response:URLResponse?, 
                                             error:Error?) -> Void in

 let task = session.dataTask(with: request, 
                completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) -> Void in
```

https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/